# simple Lie algebra $sl(2,Q_p)$ over $p$-adic field

Tags: lie-algebras, p-adic-number-theory

If $L$ is the simple Lie algebra $sl(2,Q_p)$, where $Q_p$ is the $p$-adic field. Can we find an open pro-$p$ subgroup of $Aut(L)$ such that $L(U)\otimes Q_p$ is isomorphic to $L$, for some uniform subgroup of $P$?

Comment: I guess that $P$ is that open pro-$p$ subgroup and $U$ is that uniform subgroup of it, but what is $L(U)$, and how does it get tensored with $\mathbb Q_p$? Is $L(U)$ maybe the $\mathbb Z_p$-Lie algebra associated with $U$? And are you following definitions and constructions a la Dixon/duSautoy/Mann/Segal?

Comment: Define an addition on $U$ by

$g+h=\lim{n\rightarrow\infty}(g^{p^{n}}h^{p^{n}})^{p{-n}}$

and a Lie bracket by 

$[g,h]_L=\lim{n\rightarrow\infty}[g^{p^{n}},h^{p^{n}}]^{p^{-2n}}$, here [,] is the commutator of $U$.

Comment: could you edit *your post* to make it more understandable? $P$ and $U$ are not introduced, $L(U)$ is not defined (I assume that in your comment you define $L(U)$, but you should say it).

Comment: Sorry, the above should be the definition of $L(U)$. I want to find $U$ and $P$, where $P$ is an open pro-p-subgroup of Aut(L) and $U$ a uniform subgroup of $P$.